# What does the "_8wekyb3d8bbwe" extension in Windows metro apps mean?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, windows-store-app

Metro apps in windows seem to have a special extension to their installation directory, for example the new Windows Terminal is located at `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.3.2382.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\`. I've noticed that other metro apps also have that `_8wekyb3d8bbwe` extension in their path.

I came across this while writing an AutoHotkey script that has to launch Windows Terminal, which is done with

```
Run shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

It looks similar to the installation directory path but there is no version or architecture in the command (the  `_1.3.2382.0_x64_` part is missing). However I have to specify `_8wekyb3d8bbwe` to get it working and I'm curious what this is.

What does `_8wekyb3d8bbwe` represent? What is the meaning behind it and why is it there?

Comment: It’s the partial Application User Model ID for the application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `8wekyb3d8bbwe` string eems to have no purpose except ensuring that
package names from Microsoft will not conflict with user names.

You will see in the Microsoft list at
[Package names for apps provisioned in Windows 10, version 1709](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/remove-provisioned-apps-during-update#package-names-for-apps-provisioned-in-windows-10-version-1709)
that all package names from Microsoft terminate with this string.

As to why this string was chosen and no other, I have no explanation.
Maybe some Microsoft developer just randomly hit his keyboard.
From the distribution of the letters, he might have used his left hand
for doing that.

Comment: *8wekyb3d8bbwe* is a developer identifier more than likely likely linked to the certificate used to publish the application to the store.  This would explain the reason all Microsoft UWP published to the Microsoft Store applications share the same identical hash

Answer (score 8):

`8wekyb3d8bbwe` is Microsoft's `PublisherId`, which is why all Package Names for apps released by them end in it.

Apps released by other publishers will have other IDs (for example, HP has `v10z8vjag6ke6`).

You can see a list of all of your installed packages by running `Get-AppxPackage *` in PowerShell. In the list, you can see that most apps are by Microsoft, and will have Package IDs ending in `8wekyb3d8bbwe`. You also might be able to find some released by other companies, with  other Publisher IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You start modern apps via their URL not by their exefile.

```
@Echo This takes a few seconds to run ...
@For /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%A in ('reg query HKCR /f "URL:*" /s /d ^| findstr /c:"URL:" ^| findstr /v /c:"URL: " ^| Sort') Do @Echo %%A %%B
pause
```

The above batch file lists URLs registered on your computer.

EG

```
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:calculator
```

To start the *current version* of calculator

```
calculator://
```

Comment: This is interesting. Surprisingly Windows Terminal is not listed in there. So it seems there are exceptions to this.